# How to simplify complex Oracle store procedure with many lines

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I must work with biggest Oracle store procedure with more 3000 code lines.
This procedure work fine and, fortunally, dba before me was very smart.
But I'm leared there isn't a good practice insert more line in procedure becouse it is hard to read and hard to maintance.

My question is: is there any tool that manage this complex SPO by any kind of diagram?

What is the best way to work with biggest procedure? divide it in more sub-procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the language, you'd never want 3000 lines of code in a single logical unit.  You'd want to decompose it into smaller blocks that do smaller pieces of work.

A PL/SQL IDE like SQL Developer has the ability to expand and collapse different sub-blocks so you can collapse an `IF` statement or a loop or something like that.  I assume virtually any IDE would have similar functionality.  That can make dealing with sprawling code a little more tolerable.  But the proper approach is to refactor the code into something that is actually small enough to be maintainable.